# How to enforce assembler to encode "immediate value" in specific way?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, intel, disassembly

I caught a problem on re-asselembling the disassembly.
I want byte pattern of ***re-assembled binary*** to be same with ***original binary***.
However, It wasn't.  I'll show you an example.

(I know encoding problem regarding `displacement` can be handled using [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491342/how-to-enforce-the-assembler-to-emit-code-using-using-specific-encoding).
 But this problem is about `immediate value`, not `displacement`)

1.disassembly of binary_A was :

```
83 2f 55                subl   $0x55,(%edi)
81 2f 55 00 00 00       subl   $0x55,(%edi)
```

2.parsed `1` and made `A.s` file:

```
subl   $0x55,(%edi)
subl   $0x55,(%edi)
```

3.re-assembled `A.s`.

```
83 2f 55                subl   $0x55,(%edi)
83 2f 55                subl   $0x55,(%edi)
```

As you see, byte pattern of ***re-assembled binary*** and ***original binary*** is different!

Actually, in my opinion, disassembled code in `step 1` shouldn't be the same.
Because encoding of immediate value(`0x55`)is different each other!(`55 00 00 00` and `55`).

How can I enforce the assembler to emit the exact machine code that I want?
Especially, I want `subl   $0x55,(%edi)` to be assembled as `81 2f 55 00 00 00`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The trivial way would be something like `db 81h, 2fh, 55h, 0, 0, 0`, but probably it's not what you want.

Comment: Besides Matteo's correct response, about the only way to do it is to use a different assembler that does support this feature  (NASM will)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: In GAS, it would be `.byte 0x81, 0x2f, ...`.  `db` is NASM / MASM.  But yeah MichaelPetch is right: GAS doesn't have control over the width of immediates.  With up-to-date binutils, you could use `{disp8}` / `{disp32}` prefixes ([What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046814)) to make the instruction almost the same length by using a disp32, but that's 4 bytes longer rather than 3 because the original had no displacement.

Comment: AFAIK, none of the mainstream x86 assemblers are designed to give total control over encoding choices.  **Normally people don't try to disassemble / reassemble the whole binary, just modify some bytes in an existing binary and maybe add a new section.**  Maybe try Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler (http://agner.org/optimize/) which can put labels on branch targets, so reassembling with different instruction lengths might not break everything.  But instruction-lengths aren't the only problem; section/segment ordering, alignment, and attributes (read-only / read-write) could be an issue.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you don't restrict this to GAS, then it's yet another duplicate of [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046814).  In NASM syntax, `sub [edi],  strict dword 0x55`, which is easier than what @MatteoItalia suggested if you're going to use NASM syntax. :P

Comment: Oh `NASM` support the syntax :D Your answer was very helpful for me. thanks. @PeterCordes @MichaelPetch